# c++ function gives memory alloc error

Tags: c++

The folowing function code:

```
void add_edge(int** point, int start, int end)
{   

int x;

//start->end edge
x=point[start][0];
if(x>=2)        
{
    int* temp=new int[x+1];
    for(int i=0; i<=x; i++)
        temp[i]=point[start][i];
//  delete[] point[start];
    point[start]=temp;
}
point[start][++point[start][0]]=end;

if(start==end) return;

//end->start edge
x=point[end][0];
if(x>=2)
{
    int* temp=new int[x+1];
    for(int i=0; i<=x; i++)
        temp[i]=point[end][i];
//  delete[] point[end];
    point[end]=temp;
}
point[end][++point[end][0]]=start;
}
```

has a memory allocation error which I cannot find.

From valgrind I get this:

```
==9253== Invalid write of size 4
==9253==    at 0x8048643: add_edge(int**, int, int) (c1.cpp:34) (line: point[start][++point[start][0]]=end;)
==9253==    by 0x8048C8B: main (c1.cpp:184) (line:          add_edge(point,start,end); )
==9253==  Address 0x2d6a7074 is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==9253==    at 0x4025FE5: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==9253==    by 0x80485D0: add_edge(int**, int, int) (c1.cpp:28)
==9253==    by 0x8048C8B: main (c1.cpp:184)
==9253== 
==9253== Invalid write of size 4
==9253==    at 0x80486EA: add_edge(int**, int, int) (c1.cpp:48) (line:  point[end][++point[end][0]]=start; )
==9253==    by 0x8048C8B: main (c1.cpp:184)
==9253==  Address 0x2d6a7134 is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==9253==    at 0x4025FE5: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==9253==    by 0x8048677: add_edge(int**, int, int) (c1.cpp:42)
==9253==    by 0x8048C8B: main (c1.cpp:184)
==9253== 
--9253-- REDIR: 0x41e07c0 (__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4026ccc (__GI_strlen)
```

Comment: That is an unpleasant code construct you are using there...

Comment: I also don't understand the purpose of the code. How are you representing the graph? An explanation in plain words might help us and you. It seems a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: If you follow the advice at http://sscce.org/ we might actually be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your uncommented code correctly, the first element of each subarray describes the number of following elements. It also looks like you are trying to grow the subarray by one element. If that is the case you need `new int[x+2]` (1 for growth, and 1 for the length field).

However, please find a cleaner way to write your code; `point[start][++point[start][0]]`is grotesque!

Comment: OMG that's it! new int[x+2] is the solution. I know that the code is not pleasant, I need to correct few things. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the previous array has the same size as the newly allocated array.

I suggest that you convert your code to use `std::vector` instead of primitive arrays. That gives you four benefits:

- You can always ask for the `size()` of a vector.
- When in doubt, you can replace `point[i]` with `point.at(i)` and thereby add boundary checking.
- Instead of using a `for` loop to copy an array, you can simply copy a vector using the assignment operator.
- Your code looks more like C++ and less like C.

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately the point is that I can't use vector library

Comment: @Tohil: Why not? It's an integral part of C++.

Comment: I know but it is included in my compiling specification

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately not got a C++ compiler to double check this right now, but I would suspect your `++point` line is not doing what is intended, and should probably be `++(point[start][0])` i.e. without the parentheses, you are incrementing the pointer, not the array element.

Comment: Ahh just double checked the code that this reminded me of, and the problem was doing *p++, which moves the pointer, not increments the value pointed at.